# stackpromos.com HTTPS cert is invalid

Tags: bug, status-completed, ssl

The certificate presented does not work for [stackpromos.com](https://stackpromos.com), leading to a warning in my browser about an invalid certificate.

[image: Invalid certificate for stackpromos.com; issued to *.stackexchange.com]

Comment: Ah right, I misremembered what the core of your report here was. :) Issuing a valid cert for that domain is planned on the SRE team, but there's no ETA at the moment.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My bad.

Word on the street is stackpromos.com probably isn't supposed to have a valid cert, but I linked it in [the blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/12/12/winter-bash-2017-greatest-hits-hats/) as https out of habit. Will fix as soon as I can get the blog post edited!

**Update**: Fixed.

Comment: So, who should we ping this year to get a secret hat? ;)

Comment: Still not working here FWIW...

Comment: @rogerdpack There not being a cert is by design - the error that I fixed was linking to `https` in the Winter Bash blog post, leading everyone on a certificate wild goose chase.

Comment: The SRE team has "add a cert to stackpromos.com" on their list, but it's not high up on the priority list at the moment since the domain is basically just a read-only museum of past promos, if you will.

Comment: @AdamLear I will.

Answer (score 3):

We now route this through another provider for the redirect and serve a valid cert. Sorry it didn't happen immediately - it was a "minor" domain and just wasn't the highest priority at the time.

Answer (score 1):

This is no longer relevant, since stackpromos.com domain does not exist anymore, and redirecting to https://contests.stackoverflow.com instead, which being part of stackoverflow.com domain, gets its https cert.